# What's hardware-accelerated besides -webkit-transform on mobile safari (webkit)?

Tags: sencha-touch, gpu, mobile-webkit

I'm building an application using Sencha Touch that's targeting iPads. The only way to achieve a smooth animation that I know is to use -webkit-transform css property. That works for moving things around with translate3d and scaling them, however I'm looking to change elements' dimensions (width and height). Imagine an element that grows in size to accomodate for a new child - that's what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any luck with width and height, as any transitions for these properties *won't* be hardware accelerated. What you'll get instead in Safari is a jerky animation that isn't even scaled properly. In my tests, the browser would first transition the height, then the width would snap into place abruptly, or vice versa. If all you want to do is scale an element  (change its dimensions) then you should us `-webkit-transform: scale(x, y)`.